# pqxx column names in multi table request

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

This question is specific to [libpqxx](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/).

Given an SQL statement like the following:

```
string s = "SELECT a.foo, b.bar FROM tableOne a, tableTwo b WHERE a.X=b.X"
```

and sending it to a pqxx transaction:

```
trans.exec(s.c_str(), s.c_str());
```

What names will the columns have in the result field?

In other words, assuming 1 row is selected:

```
pqxx::result::const_iterator row = result.begin();
int foo = row->at(FOO_COLUMN).as<int>();
int bar = row->at(BAR_COLUMN).as<int>();
```

What values should FOO_COLUMN and BAR_COLUMN have? Would they be "a.foo" and "b.bar", respectively?

If the SQL statement renamed the variables using the "as" keyword, then I suppose the column name would be whatever "as" set it to, is that right?

Normally I would try an SQL and print the column values, but as I am developing both the software and the database itself, doing that test is not very easy right now.

Thanks!

Comment: `at` takes a `size_type` (which is an unsigned long) so presumably you'd use position numbers.

Comment: Yes, there is a version of at which takes a column position, and if I have to, I can use that as a work around. But I think the string version is nicer in case the SQL changes in the future. So I am curious what name the columns have..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names are going to be `foo` and `bar`. If they were aliases in the query, then the aliases would be returned, the original names being lost.

Column names in results never include table names.

If they were named `tablename.colname`, it would be ambiguous anyway because `SELECT 1 as "foo.colname"` is valid and produces a column `foo.colname` despite the fact there is no `foo` table.

The way to identify the table from which a column originates, when it applies, is to call `pqxx::result::column_table(column_number)` which returns the `oid` of the table. The table's name is not available directly but could be queried in `pg_class` with the `oid`.

Also note that column names don't have to be unique within a resultset. `SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS a` is valid and produces two columns with exactly the same name.

Comment: Aha, so the PostgreSQL database returns column names as part of its response and those are what get used in the pqxx::result tuples?